# Float equality comparison using epsilon and hash code in Swift?

Tags: swift, floating-point, precision, hashcode

I want to create Set of floats, compared using epsilon. However if some values can produce different hash codes, but be equal is you compare them this way:

```
func isEqual(to other: Float, usingEpsilon epsilon: Float) -> Bool {
    abs(other - self) < epsilon
}
```

How to create an approopriative hashCode in this case?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. This problem is essentially equivalent to a hashmap of non-overlapping ranges, where you have a `Double` key and want to find the range in the map that contains the key. That's not possible through hashing. You could instead used a tree-based Set/Dictionary, however that will have `O(log(n))` instead of `O(1)` lookup times.

Comment: Suppose (for example) that you use a constant epsilon of `0.15`. Then under this definition of equality, `0.0` would be equal to `0.1`, so they'd have to have the same hash. But then also `0.1` would be equal to `0.2`, which would be equal to `0.3`, etc., so `0.1` would have to have the same hash as `0.2`, which would have to have the same hash as `0.3`, and so on. The only way to make this work would be to have a constant hash. (And you'd also be breaking the fundamental transitivity property of equality: 0.1 would be equal to 0.2, and 0.2 to 0.3, but 0.1 would not be equal to 0.3.)